# Urn Problem - black and white balls, infinite trials.

Tags: probability, random-walk

Imagine that there are 10 black balls and 20 white balls in an urn. Two balls are removed at random from the urn. The second ball removed is recolored, such that it matches the color of the first ball, then we put the balls back into the urn and repeat this process indefinitely. What is the probability that all the balls in the urn turn black?

My approach is to model this problem similar to gambler's ruin problem. We start with 20 white balls and we should find out the probability that we reach the absorbing state of 0. We have three possibilities after every trial, to stay in the same state(no change in the number of white balls of urn after the trial), one white ball less(we go to the state i-1), on white ball more(we go to the state i+1). P varies at each trial and only depends on the current state. Is this method feasible? or should I look for variants of Polya urns?

Comment: What are we interested in? The probability that we end up with all white?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I would assume so.

Comment: I might be wrong, but since the overall probability of drawing a white before drawing a black is more than $1/2$, wouldn't after infinite trials the $P(\text{all white}) \to 1$?

Comment: I will edit the question. I am sorry. The probability that we end up with all black. Which is similar to the ruin of the gambler, losing all his capital or in this case losing all 20 white balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* a pure gambler's ruin problem. While there are balls of each colour in the urn, with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ the number of black decreases by $1$, and with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ it increases by $1$. The ties are irrelevant.

Comment: After a few trials, or in this case even in the first trial, how is the probability 1/2 for drawing a black ball first and then a white ball? because there are 10 black balls and 20 white balls initially, I have 4 cases, in which I draw BB, BW, WB, WW. As the composition of the urn changes, shouldn't we have a probability which changes at each trial?

Comment: loosely speaking, It couldn't be 1/2 AFAIU, because we can also stay in the same state with some probability.

Comment: The probability of WB is the same as the probability of BW. One could claim (and I do) that after a while this should be "obvious." All permutations of the balls are equally likely. But if you wish you can do a calculation, $b$ black, $w$ white. The probability first is black and scond is white is $\frac{b}{b+w}\frac{w}{b+w-1}$. This is the same as probability of white then black.

Comment: About your previous comment: If we cared about the **length** of the game, BB and WW would be important. But if we are only interested in the probability of getting to all black, we can discard all the plays in which we got no change.

Comment: Yes, The probability that WB and BW at every trial is equal. but it varies at each trial, i.e,say at state i p(BW)=p(WB)=k and at state j p(BW)=p(WB)=m. because the composition of the urn has changed.

Comment: When we are recording what happened, if we record only the *changes*, we will know who won. So only the *conditional* probabilities, *given* there was a change, matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand it now. The conditional proabability comment helped.

Comment: You are welcome. Often the things that after a while become "obvious" (BW and WB are equally likely, BB and WW are irrelevant) take a while to become clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, As long as there are white balls and black balls, the probability of increasing whites $W/(B+W) * B/(B+W-1)$ is equal to probability of increasing blacks $B/(B+W) * W/(B+W-1)$, so the process is as likely to go toward W as to go toward B.  But once we reach a state of only one color the probabilities are 1 (for no change) and 0 (for change).  The expected length of the chain of events toward all W is much shorter than that to all B.  This is where the difference appears.  In the end, the probability of all B is much smaller than all W, so $P[all B]<<0.50$.